# How to use bash script as run configuration in PyCharm 2018.1 PRO?

Tags: pycharm

I use some bash scripts in my project as debug/run configuration. It copies files, start some services etc. Some of them prepare zipped archives etc.

Just updated my PyCharm PE to 2018.1 (Build #PY-181.4203.547), built on March 26, 2018 and got a problem. There is no more shell scripts option in debug/run configuration. My old configurations became incorrect.

[image]

And in available configs there is nothing that could be used.

[image]

There are 'external tools' settings, where I could add my scripts as tools, but looks like it is common settings for all project.

**What can I do?**

Comment: Bash support is a separate 3rd party plugin. Please check if it's installed and enabled. (P.S. As a possible alternative: maybe you can execute those scripts via Grunt/Gulp/npm ? They are task runners and are suitable for such tasks and IDE supports creating Run Configurations for them (or even execute them directly via appropriate tool window)... )

Comment: Updating Bash plugin solved a problem. I was sure that it is only for "Bash language support for the IntelliJ platform. Supports syntax highlighting, rename refactoring, documentation lookup, inspections, quickfixes and much more." but not for run configs.